# Syncing users between two azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to sync users from one azure active directory to another azure active directory. When searching for this I found a lot of options (using AAD connect for example) to sync on premises AD to azure active directory is there a way to do this between 2 actual AAD's.

What I want to achieve is that the users and groups from an office365(what means it has an AAD) gets synced to another azure active directory (moving the second active directory into the 365 AAD is not an option). And so when a user gets added to the 365 it gets added to the other AAD but also when it gets removed (the second active directory has no need for backwards syncing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such settings/tool we can sync the users between different Azure AD.

To achieve the goal, you need to write the code yourself. For example, you can write a service which pull the users from the two Azure AD and compare them. Then sync the users using the [Azure AD Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the response, as far as I found there was also not a simple tool for this (I will probably look into doing it with Azure graph)

Comment: If you develop the tool, you need to consider how to implement password synchronization carefully. As far as I know, the password can't be exported from Azure AD. As an alternative, you may use an intermediate relay for syncing accounts between two Azure AD. For example, AD Connect + PIM/MIM. Please see following article for more details. [Topologies for Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-topologies)

Comment: Is there any way to add external users programmatically? Like you can do in the Azure Portal

Comment: Yes, we are able to use the Azure Active Directory B2B collaboration API to achieve the goal. More detail refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-api).

Comment: I did some initial testing with it (using postman to do the API calls) and this is most likely what we are going to use